# How do you access an array element in Perl when you have the name of the array stored as an element of another array?

Tags: arrays, perl, element

Suppose I have this piece of code.

It has an array 'arr' storing the names of other arrays like 'et', 'rt' etc...

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    $\="\n";
    @arr = ("$et", "\$rt", "\$ee", "\$re", "\$ec", "\$epc", "\$rc", "\$rpc", "\$euc", "\$ruc", "\$ekc", "\$rkc");
    @et = (100, 1000, 1100, 1200, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900);
    .
    .
    .
```

And other arrays rt, ee similarly defined..

How do I access say $et[2]? I've tried $arr[0][2], $($arr[0])[2] and many other variations but nothing seems to work. Any solution?

Comment: Check `ARRAYS OF ARRAYS`, `HASHES OF ARRAYS`, `ARRAYS OF HASHES`, `HASHES OF HASHES` => http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea to work this way. What you probably want is not to store the names of other arrays, but references to it, e.g.

```
my @et = ( 100,1000,1100,1200,... );
my @arr = ( \@et,... )
```

then you can access the second element from @et using @arr with $arr[0][1]:

- $arr[0] -> \@et (reference to @et)
- $arr[0][1] -> second element of @et

often you see instead people write $arr[0]->[1], which is exactly the same, only 2 bytes longer :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't use `use strict;` (or, at least, not `use strict refs;`).

You need `${$arr[0]}[2]`, but you store the plain name (`"et"`) in `@arr`:

```
@arr = ("et", "rt",);
@et = (100, 1000, 1100, 1200, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900);

print ${$arr[0]}[2], "\n";
```

It isn't good style, though.  You'd be better off using a hash indexed by 'array name' with the arrays (or array refs) as the value associated with the key:

```
my %arr = ( "et" => [100, 1000, 1100], "rt" => [200, 2000, 2200] );

print $arr{et}->[2], "\n";
```